# bower relink paths with yeoman and grunt

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, bower

I had a previous yeoman version working with `angular-generator`. I updated everything, including node, npm, bower and yeoman.

Before this update I had `app/bower_components` now they are siblings `app` and `bower_components`. When running `grunt serve` or `grunt build` bower links everything back to:

```
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

to get it working it should be

```
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

but grunt changes it back. I'm thinking the issue is with where grunt picks this route from.

I created a second project with the new version of generator and compared `bower.json`, `.bowerrc`and `gruntfile.js` and everything seems ok but I still don't get a correct link thus build does not work though serve runs perfectly.

Any hint on what should I change to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the comment in html

```
<!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
```

instead of

```
<!-- build:css styles/vendor.css -->
```

and

```
<!-- build:js({.,app}) scripts/vendor.js -->
```

instead of

```
<!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->
```

Notice the `(.)` and `{.,app}` in each case. The second one is different because I want another script located in app/scripts/lib

```
<script src="scripts/lib/other.script.js"></script>
```